# IdentityServer4 database for access token issuer

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver4, http-token-authentication

I am completely new to IdentityServer4 and I cannot figure out how does it create an access token from userid (username?) and secret (password?). Here are some sub questions which makes me confused:

a) Is there a seperate database running for IdentityServer, or I should use whatever DB is used for registration (in case of a single API (other) handling registration)?

b) If there is a seperate database, how does it sync with DB for identity server?

c) Does a registration API need to have some changes too, to work with 
IdentityServer? Or is it possible to just register it as a service?

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer4 has `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` to validate the resource owner password credential. You can implement this interface and it enables you to use any user store.

[IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator.cs) has an implementation.

Another example is [here](https://www.google.com.tr/amp/s/damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/amp/).